# Docker instances with same name get overwritten

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm working in a Windows environment, using most recent version of Docker and using Docker Compose.  What I want is each project on my hard drive to have its own folder and insides its corresponding `docker-compose.yml` file.

When I run:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

for the specific files in a project it overwrites the last projects instances.  I believe this is because I use the same names for all projects (Nginx, db etc).

How can I stop this behavior?  I want, for example, my database instance for each project to persist so when I start it up again after working on other projects it will still have the same data.  I would much prefer not to name the instances different names for every project...I have a large amount of them and it's a waste of my time to reconfigure these files every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better isolation on docker-compose level you can use COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME (see https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name)

So create for example docker-compose-script.bat file with following content:

```
set COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=your_project_name
docker-compose %*
```

%* - will allow you to pass every docker-compose command via your script to docker-compose so you can easily make: `docker-compose-script.bat up -d`

please be aware to NOT name your .bat script with docker-compose.bat because you will land in endless loop.